# Cannot turn on global-auto-complete-mode

Tags: init-file, auto-complete-mode

I installed auto-complete by `M-x list-packages`, navigating to the `auto-complete` package, and hit the Install button. The emacswiki page says that doing so will configure the load-path so auto-complete.el will be loaded correctly.

I have this in my init.el

`(require 'auto-complete)
(global-auto-complete-mode t)`

and emacs gives the following error:
File error: Cannot open load file, not a directory, auto-complete

I tried adding the directory containing `auto-complete.el` to the `load-path` but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: You should need to manually update the `load-path` if you are installing packages using the package manager (like you do using `M-x list-packages`). I would recommend removing all instances of you manually updating the `load-path` and then see if the issue persists after restarting emacs. If the issue is still there, see if you can recreate the problem in an `emacs -Q` session. Also, you need to have `(package-initialize)` in your config.

Comment: According to http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LoadPath, load-path is automatically configured to handle packages installed with the package manager.

Comment: Sorry, that was a big typo on my part, I meant that you **shouldn't** need to manually update.

Comment: ```(package-initialize)``` fixed it!

Comment: If you are getting that error at emacs startup, try starting emacs as usual but with `--debug-init` option at the command line. And then you can paste here (update your question with) the error backtrace you get.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The File error in the original post is from --debug-init.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, the solution is to ensure that `(package-initialize)` is in the emacs config.

---

From the [Package Installation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Package-Installation.html) section of the emacs Manual,

> In some circumstances, you may want to load packages explicitly in your init file (usually because some other code in your init file depends on a package). In that case, your init file should call the function `package-initialize`.

I would say that in *almost all circumstances* it would be needed to have `(package-initialize)` in the very beginning of the user's init file.