# How to turn typopunct minor mode on globally

Tags: init-file, minor-mode, typography

I want to be able to use [typopunct](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TypographicalPunctuationMarks) minor mode globally.

I have tried to add `(global-typopunct-mode 1)` to my init file, like so

```elisp
;; Typopunct mode
(require 'typopunct)
(typopunct-change-language 'english t)
(global-typopunct-mode 1)
```

but I get this error: Symbol's function definition is void: global-typopunct-mode.
Then I thought that the problem could be something similar to [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19974/cannot-turn-on-global-auto-complete-mode) post, but I have package-initalize on my init.el file (as shown below)

```elisp
;; MELPA controls
(when (>= emacs-major-version 24)  
  (require 'package)
  (setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
  ;; (add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/")) 
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")) ;; install it manually
  ;;(add-to-list 'package-archives '("ox-odt" . "https://kjambunathan.github.io/elpa/"))
  (package-initialize))
```

which makes me believe that typopunct was not meant to be activated globally... Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You might want to try making this minor mode global yourself. Take a look at docstrings for `define-globalized-minor-mode` and `define-global-minor-mode`.

Comment: Are you sure you really want it to be "global" though?  This might cause annoying results with various programming languages. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it. Note: I am a newbie to elisp so any comments/corrections are most welcome.
Just add the following line to the [typopunct.el](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/typopunct.el) file after the `define-minor-mode typopunct-mode`

```elisp
(define-globalized-minor-mode global-typopunct-mode typopunct-mode (lambda () (typopunct-mode 1)))
```

From the documentation I should also define a non-globalized version, so that people can use (or disable) it in individual buffers, but that is beyond me at this point :-). If anyone wants to add it please go ahead!

**Update**

As suggested by Tobias this more selective version avoids messing up with programming modes.

```elisp
(define-globalized-minor-mode global-typopunct-mode typopunct-mode (lambda () (when (null (derived-mode-p 'prog-mode)) (typopunct-mode))))
```

Comment: You've already got a non-globalized version: `typopunct-mode`.  To disable it, you would do `(add-hook 'c-mode #'(lambda () (typopunct-mode -1)))` (e.g., to disable it for C files).

Comment: One could be a bit more selective, e.g.: `(lambda () (when (null (derived-mode-p 'prog-mode)) (typopunct-mode)))`.